# Turn all character dates columns in a dataframe to dates columns r

Tags: r

I have a dataset with more than 50 date columns. While importing the dataset into R using fread or csv function-all date columns were formatted as character columns. While I could spend half a day, converting each column at a time, I'm thinking some R expert might have figured out a better way to convert the format of a large number of columns at once.

Is there an efficient way to convert a list of columns into properly date formatted columns in one swoop?

My dummy data is as follows:

[image]

Comment: FYI in case you have any control over your input csv files, if the dates are formatted as YYYY-MM-DD they will be auto-detected and read as dates with `fread` (and probably other functions too, but I'm only familiar with fread)

Comment: Yes, I formatted the dates column as YYYY-MM-DD for the same reason in SQL(verified and was formatted) and used fread in r expecting correct handling of the dates column. But I still faced the same issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Updated**
I would like to thank Mr. @Gregor Thomas for offering a valuable tip to be added to my solution. We assume that all of your date columns have a `date` suffix so that we can tell `across` function to only apply Date transformations on them.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  mutate(across(ends_with("date"), ~ as.Date(.x, format = "%m/%d/%Y")))

# A tibble: 2 x 4
     id generic_name index_date ami_pre_date
  <dbl> <chr>        <date>     <date>      
1     1 ato          2016-10-27 2015-10-20  
2     2 sim          2017-07-12 2026-05-01
```

**Data**

```
structure(list(id = c(1, 2), generic_name = c("ato", "sim"), 
    index_date = c("10/27/2016", "7/12/2017"), ami_pre_date = c("10/20/2015", 
    "5/1/2026")), row.names = c(NA, -2L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: In case OP has more non-date columns scattered throughout, something like  `across(ends_with("date"), ...)` might be better.

Comment: You are quite right Mr. Thomas. I will add this to my solution with your permission. Thank you very much.

Comment: @Gregor I am thinking the same. How to write an r code that ends_with("date"). Can you please provide an example.

Comment: @PrajwalManiPradhan you can use Anoushiravan's answer, but replace `-c(1, 2)` (which says "operate across all columns except the first two") with `ends_with("date")` (which says "operate across all columns that end with "date"").

Comment: Thank you Anoushiravan and Gregor! yes, the assumption is correct and valid.

Answer (score 1):

A `base R`solution with `lapply`:

```
df[grepl("date$", names(df))] <- lapply(df[grepl("date$", names(df))], function(x) as.Date(x, format = "%m/%d/%Y"))
```

Result:

```
df
# A tibble: 2 x 4
     id generic_name index_date ami_pre_date
  <dbl> <chr>        <date>     <date>      
1     1 ato          2016-10-27 2015-10-20  
2     2 sim          2017-07-12 2026-05-01
```

Data: (thanks to @Anoushiravan)

```
df <- structure(list(id = c(1, 2), generic_name = c("ato", "sim"), 
    index_date = c("10/27/2016", "7/12/2017"), ami_pre_date = c("10/20/2015", 
    "5/1/2026")), row.names = c(NA, -2L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: Thank you Chris!

Answer (score 1):

We can use `anydate`

```
library(anytime)
library(dplyr)
df  %>% 
  mutate(across(contains('date'), anydate))
# A tibble: 2 x 4
#     id generic_name index_date ami_pre_date
#  <dbl> <chr>        <date>     <date>      
#1     1 ato          2016-10-27 2015-10-20  
#2     2 sim          2017-07-12 2026-05-01
```

> 